# Tensorflow outputs nan for basic object detection/classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, tensorflow, cnn, object-detection

I am receiving `nan` as my accuracy and loss outputs after each epoch for basic object detection in tensorflow. Also, my results (classification and bounding box coords) are `nan`.

How do I get proper results?
Another side question, why are input, pooling layers, and flatten layers params zero when compiling model?

Link to my full code and training data at: https://github.com/arojas314/data-sharing.git

Model snippet:

```py
'''
Feature extractor is the CNN that is made up of convolution and pooling layers.
'''
def feature_extractor(inputs):
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, activation='relu', kernel_size=3, input_shape=(424, 424, 3))(inputs)
    x = tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D((2, 2))(x)

    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=3,activation='relu')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D((2, 2))(x)

    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size=3,activation='relu')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D((2, 2))(x)

    return x

'''
dense_layers adds a flatten and dense layer.
This will follow the feature extraction layers
'''
def dense_layers(inputs):
    x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(inputs)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
    return x


'''
Classifier defines the classification output.
This has a set of fully connected layers and a softmax layer.
'''
def classifier(inputs):
    classification_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax', name = 'classification')(inputs)
    # classification_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax', name = 'classification')(inputs) # works but so should above
    return classification_output


'''
This function defines the regression output for bounding box prediction.
Note that we have four outputs corresponding to (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)
'''
def bounding_box_regression(inputs):
    bounding_box_regression_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = '4', name = 'bounding_box')(inputs)
    return bounding_box_regression_output


def final_model(inputs):
    feature_cnn = feature_extractor(inputs)
    dense_output = dense_layers(feature_cnn)

    '''
    The model branches here.
    The dense layer's output gets fed into two branches:
    classification_output and bounding_box_output
    '''
    classification_output = classifier(dense_output)
    bounding_box_output = bounding_box_regression(dense_output)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = [classification_output, bounding_box_output])

    return model


def define_and_compile_model(inputs):
    model = final_model(inputs)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss = {'classification' : 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                          'bounding_box' : 'mse'
                         },
                  metrics = {'classification' : 'accuracy',
                             'bounding_box' : 'mse'
                            })
    # Returns full and compiled model
    return model



inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(424, 424, 3))
# inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, 424, 424, 3))
model = define_and_compile_model(inputs)

# print model layers
model.summary()
```

Fitting model:

```py
# Combine train bbox and train labels into dictionary
trainTargets = {
    "classification": training_labels,
    "bounding_box": training_bboxes
}

testTargets = {
    "classification": test_labels,
    "bounding_box": test_bboxes
}

EPOCHS = 5 # 45
steps_per_epoch = trainTargets["bounding_box"].shape[0]//BATCH_SIZE  # need number of training items only!
validation_steps = 1

history = model.fit(training_images, trainTargets,
                    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
                    validation_data=(test_images, testTargets),
                    validation_steps=validation_steps, epochs=EPOCHS)
```